# Which programming language should I start with in game dev?

Tags: software-engineering, graphics-programming

I am a front end web developer and I've always been interested in building games.  I work primarily with HTML, CSS, PHP, and JavaScript on a daily basis, so I'm not new to coding.  I would like to know which language/platform would be most useful for me to build a simple, 2D, art heavy game, like something you'd see on the Super Nintendo.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this with the languages and tools you already know; in general the tools you already know are going to be the "best" ones to get started with.

Comment: in addition, if theres some tool you want to use, you would obviously have to go with the languages that are supported

Comment: Unity supports Unityscript, which is custom language based on JavaScript. It also handles 2D really well.

Comment: If you're a web developer, how about webgl: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/ ?